# Summation of series with exponential terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is their an analytical expression for the summation

$\displaystyle \sum_{m, n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-cm^2 - dn^2} $. Here $m, n$ are integers and $0< c,d < \infty$.

Comment: What kind of notation is that? Moreover $\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}}\exp\left(cm^2+dn^2\right)$ is clearly divergent if $c,d > 0$.

Comment: Do you mean $e^{cm^2+dn^2} $? And what is $c$ and xd$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be written as $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-cn^2} \cdot \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-dm^2}$, so it is sufficient to consider only one such factor. Also,
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-cn^2} = 1 + 2 \sum_{n =1}^\infty e^{-cn^2}
$$ 
Note that the series converges extremely rapidly for all $c > 0$.

The expression
$$
\vartheta_3(z,q) =  1 + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n^2} \cos 2 n z
$$
is known as a (Jacobi) Theta function and equals the sum in question for $z = 0, q = e^{-c}$. See the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) and the NIST Handbook on Special Functions ch. 20.

Some special values are known in closed form, e.g.
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-\pi n^2} = \frac{\root{4}\of{\pi}}{\Gamma(\frac{3} {4})},
\quad
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-5 \pi n^2} = \frac{\root{4}\of{225\pi + 100 \sqrt{5\pi}}}{5 \Gamma(\frac{3}{4})} .
$$